# AppEngine Search - numeric operators not working?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

I'm trying to use the search service on app engine... I've run into a problem when I try to use numeric operators. I get an InvalidRequest error.

At first I thought it was something else with my query, but when I use the examples from the documentation I get the same results.

For example, this works:

author:"Rose Jones" length = 15

but this example, copied straight from the docs, throws an InvalidRequest error:

author:"Rose Jones" length > 15

As far as I can tell, any operator other than = isn't working.

Can anyone help? :)

edit - code per request:

```
INDEX_NAME = 'sample'

query_string = 'author:"Rose Jones" length > 15'

logging.info('final query string: '+query_string)

try:
    results = search.Index(name=INDEX_NAME).search(query_string)
except search.Error:
    logging.exception('Search failed')
    self.errorManager.add('search6')
```

Comment: Have you tested on a deployed version as well as with the SDK? The SDK version doesn't seem to be very good.

Comment: This behaviour is on production. I don't know, maybe I'm missing something awfully obvious. I have been looking at this code for a while.

Comment: There was some processing going on before and after the snippet in the code above, so I stripped everything out from the handler but the above...same results. Change the >  to a = and the query is accepted. Keep the > and it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found the issue. It sounds a bit silly (of me!), but here goes:

Using operators other than = seems to require that the field exists somewhere in your schema/index already.

So if you say length > 15, you need to have a document with 'length' as an attribute or it will fail.

While length = 15 won't make the same complaint, and will just return zero results.

I was basically building a query constructor and was throwing queries against the search in order to check my syntax...I assumed there was a syntax problem because one type of query was accepted while the other wasn't, but it seems comparisons other than equality need matching data in the index, at the moment anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on the documentation on [filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) for Java

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setFilter("height < 72");
```

or for Python [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter)

```
q.filter('height >', 42).filter('city =', 'Seattle')
q.filter('user =', users.get_current_user())
```

Comment: I should note I'm using python...I will add code per Wooble's request also.

Comment: OP is trying to use the new experimental Search API, not to search the datastore indexes.